# Error en la instancia en SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Tags: c#

Alguna solución ? , no me aparece la instancia ,gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No esta clara tu pregunta, agrega tu codigo y especifica el error.

Comment: deberias explicarte un poco mejor, o subir alguna imagen del problema que se presenta en el Sql Server

Comment: Revisa primero si el servicio de SQL está en ejecución. Revisa este [enlace](http://geeks.ms/jalarcon/2013/11/17/truco-acceder-a-sql-server-configuration-manager-en-windows-8/) para obtener mas información.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal, 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Cambiaste la región a españa  antes de instalar?